# UnBarbarian Temporary HP

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores, barbarian, hit-points, rage

An Unchained Barbarian gets +4 Constitution and +2 HP per level while Raging. Are these stacking bonuses to temporary HP?

(Assuming a 7th level UnBarbarian) As a secondary question: Does temporary Con gives temporary HP based on the **score** gained or the **modifiers** gained? So since it gives +4 Con and is level 7, would that give 28 HP or 14 HP?

So if they do stack, at level 7, would I be getting 42 temporary HP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## There's nothing *to* stack

An [unchained barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/barbarian-unchained/) does *not* see her Constitution score increase when she [rages](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/barbarian-unchained/#TOC-Rage-Ex-). That is, the unchained barbarian's rage says

> While in a rage, a[n unchained] barbarian gains a +2 bonus on melee attack rolls, melee damage rolls, thrown weapon damage rolls, and Will saving throws. In addition, she takes a –2 penalty to Armor Class. She also gains 2 temporary hit points per Hit Die. These temporary hit points are lost first when a character takes damage, disappear when the rage ends, and are not replenished if the barbarian enters a rage again within 1 minute of her previous rage.

These temporary hp an unchained barbarian gains while raging are, essentially, an easier to track *replacement* for the morale bonus to Constitution received by a traditional [raging](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/#TOC-Rage-Ex-) [barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/), much like the bonus on attack rolls and damage rolls are an easier to track replacement for the traditional raging barbarian's morale bonus to her Strength score.

Were an unchained barbarian to benefit from an effect that increased her Constitution score, she *would* while raging gain the temporary hp from the rage *and* additional hp from her increased [Constitution](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/#Constitution_Con), but a typical unchained barbarian gains *no* bonus to her Constitution score due to her rage.

Comment: I get what you're saying. I was mixing together regular Barbarian and Unchained Barbarian and had not realized that Unchained lost the +4 Str/Con in favor of a more direct source of a +2 to everything.

Answer (score -5):

The bonuses stack.

When your Constitution is modified, your hp change accordingly. If you gain +2 Con, you get +1 hp per Hit Die. So +4 Con at level 7 usually gives +2 hp * 7 HD = +14 hp.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. What an unusual way to start your tenure! I edited your answer to put it into standard game terms (like hp for hit points, capitalizing appropriately, and omitting a reference to *health*); I hope that's okay. I'd like to note that this answer *is* correct, but the answer omits any mention of the unchained barbarian *not* getting a bonus to Con during a rage—even though the question assumes that's true—, which I thought was important enough to post my own answer; I hope that's okay, too. Anyway, thank you for participating and for trying to help strangers.

Comment: Should HP not be capitalized? It is an initialism, which are usually capitalized. Also, I wasn't familiar with the specific class being mentioned, only the rules for Constitution change. Thanks for editing, and I think your answer is worthwhile. Cheers.

Comment: [Stylistically](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6662/8610) *Pathfinder* doesn't capitalize hp, as borne out by monster entries like the [skeleton](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/skeleton-medium/). I think it's a holdover from early *3.5e* when stat blocks were paragraphs to make Hit Dice (HD) more clearly different from hit points (hp). Your welcome for the edit… and [consider adding your Location to your profile](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7013/8610) so I know if I'm supposed to hear your *Cheers* in my head like the U. S. sitcom or James Bond. `:-)`